# should ObjectContexts in Entity Framework 5 be singletons?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

When using ObjectContext in EF 5, should it be a singleton or is it better to create new instance every time like SqlConnection. If so, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create and dispose the context as soon as possible. Quote from the [`guidelines on MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx):

> Here are some general guidelines when deciding on the lifetime of the
>   context:
>
> - When working with long-running context consider the following:
> - As you load more objects and their references into memory, the memory
>     consumption of the context may increase rapidly. This may cause performance issues.
> - Remember to dispose of the context when it is no
>     longer required.
> - If an exception causes the context to be in an
>     unrecoverable state, the whole application may terminate. The chances
>     of running into concurrency-related issues increase as the gap between
>     the time when the data is queried and updated grows.
> - When working with Web applications, use a context instance per request.
> - When working with Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) or Windows Forms, use a
>     context instance per form. This lets you use change-tracking
>     functionality that context provides.